# Python c подкдюченной MS SQL, как в запрос SQL вставить переменную на Python

Tags: python, sql, запрос, переменные, ввод

Запрос SQL тащит сводный отчет за период времени формата дд.мес.год, есть начало периода и конец периода. Я так понимаю что в 01.03.2022 (01-число,03-число,2022-число, а разделительные точки это строка). Как создать переменную в Питоне чтоб начало и конец периода вводить с клавиатуры при запущеной программе питона, а не менять даты каждый раз руками в SQL запросе, пример моего когда и выходящая ошибка.

```
date1 = input()
date2 = input()
for row in cursor.execute("""declare @DStart datetime, @DFinish datetime, @SFio varchar(50),  @SPodr varchar(50), @CKorp bit, @CSoft bit, @cMetal bit, @COhr bit
-- начало периода
set @DStart=convert(datetime,'date1',104)   --где date1 если вписать руками '01.03.2022'
-- конец периода
set @DFinish=convert(datetime,'date2',104)  --где date1 если вписать '09.03.2022' отчет построит
```

а с моими переменными python переменными date1 и date2 код выдает такую ошибку:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "G:\t_bot\connection.py", line 23, in 
for row in cursor.execute("""declare @DStart datetime, @DFinish datetime, @SFio varchar(50),  @SPodr varchar(50), @CKorp bit, @CSoft bit, @cMetal bit, @COhr bit
pyodbc.ProgrammingError: ('42S22', '[42S22] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Недопустимое имя столбца "date1". (207) (SQLExecDirectW); [42S22] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Недопустимое имя столбца "date2". (207)')

Помогите как вводить произвольные даты с клавиатуры при запуске программы?

Answer (score 2):

Используйте параметризированные запросы:

```
for row in cursor.execute("""declare @DStart datetime, @DFinish datetime, @SFio varchar(50),  @SPodr varchar(50), @CKorp bit, @CSoft bit, @cMetal bit, @COhr bit
-- начало периода
set @DStart=convert(datetime,%{date1}s,104)   --где date1 если вписать руками '01.03.2022'
-- конец периода
set @DFinish=convert(datetime,%{date2}s,104)  --где date1 если вписать '09.03.2022' отчет построит", 
{'date1' : date1, 'date2' : date2})
```

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlcursor-execute.html

Comment: **pyodbc.ProgrammingError: ('42000', '[42000] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]Syntax error, permission violation, or other nonspecific error (0) (SQLExecDirectW)')** - выдает такую ошибку

Comment: Хм. Возможно, MS SQL коннектор не поддерживает именованные параметры. А если так: `convert(datetime,%s,104)`, а `'date1' : date1, 'date2' : date2}` заменить на просто `,date1, date2`?

Answer (score -2):

Все как всегда оказалось намного проще. Просто передал в запрос строку!!!
Все работает, всем спасибо!!!

````
d1 = str(input())
d2 = str(input())

for row in cursor.execute("""declare @DStart datetime, @DFinish datetime, @SFio varchar(50),  @SPodr varchar(50), @CKorp bit, @CSoft bit, @cMetal bit, @COhr bit
-- начало периода
set @DStart=convert(datetime,'"""+ d1 +"""',104)
-- конец периода
set @DFinish=convert(datetime,'"""+ d2 +"""' ,104)```
````

Comment: так вы даете возможность злоумышленникам [выполнить любой запрос](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%92%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_SQL-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0) к вашей базе (например, прочитать хеши паролей)